# Crossrider: Trigger action to open popup

Tags: javascript, crossrider

I need some insight about the browser action that triggers the popup.

Can I open a popup from one of the following scenarios?

1. Trigger an action to open popup from a page on a website?
2. Trigger an action to open popup from within extension scope?

Is there way to do this, or the popup controlling is only possible from background scope?

Answer (score 2):

The popup can only be opened by clicking on the browser action button and cannot be triggered/opened via code in any scope. Even in the background scope, you can set the configure the browser action, but you cannot open it.

[**Disclosure**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: Okay. In that case, can you guide me in how to implement a custom popup using an iframe with Crossrider?

Comment: You can get an idea from the following [recent question from the Crossrider forum](https://getsatisfaction.com/crossrider/topics/how-to-implement-click-on-context-menu-to-show-pop-up-form-entry).

Comment: Thanks. But I was thinking on using an iframe to inject code.. Is this a good practice on Crossrider Framework?

Comment: How you build the popup is up to you. The purpose of the reference was to give you an idea of how to achieve opening the popup from your extension code. There is enough there information to implement the iframe version yourself. However, if you have more specific questions about the iframe implementation, please feel free to ask.